# Add element to array if condition in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, conditional-statements, push

I'm trying to do a query to add an element to an array in a document in a mongodb collection, only if this element passes a certain condition.

```js
{
    _id: ObjectId,
    author: String,
    answers: [
        { user: 'user1', answer: 'hello1' },
        { user: 'user2', answer: 'hello2' },
        { user: 'user3', answer: 'hello3' },
    ]
}
```

Now, passing an object like this: `{ user: 'user1', answer: 'hello world' }` to my endpoint, I would like the database to check if the user who answered had already answered and if he already had, return an error or something like in MySQL (updatedRows: n) and instead, if the user hadn't already answered, simply push his answer at the bottom of the array of answers

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it OK for the match on `user` and `answer` to apply to more than one author?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this sample ::

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

// Connection URL
const url = 'your DB url';

// Create a new MongoClient - initializing client
const client = new MongoClient(url);

// Use connect method to connect to the Server    
client.connect(async function (err, db) {
    if (err) console.log('Err in connection ::', err)
    console.log("Connected successfully to server");
    try {
        let database = db.db();
        let conn = database.collection('yourCollectionName')

        /** This is what exactly needed, just pass 'user1' taken from input object
            & pass it in filter query, So if the user already exists in array then the record won't be added,
              otherwise will be pushed to array. */

        let res = await conn.updateOne({ "author": "me",'answers.user': {$ne : 'user1'} }, {
            $push: {
                answers: {
                    "user": "user1",
                    "answer": "hello world"
                }
            }
        })

        if (res.result && res.result.nModified) {
            console.log('Added new record')
        } else {
            console.log('Record already exists')
        }
        client.close();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error ::', error)
        client.close();

    }
});
```

In `if` clause we're checking `res.result.nModified` to be a positive integer in order to say record inserted, otherwise it will be falsy value i.e; 0 then duplicate record exists.

**Ref :** [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/index.html), [updateOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/index.html)